# Simple Python Function Syntax Error Question

Tags: python

I am very new to the programming world so please take it easy on me if this is not a good question. Anyways, I am trying to create my first function in Python and I keep getting a syntax error.

Specifically, this is what I am entering into Python:

```
def convert (fahr):
    cels = fahr *1.8 + 32
    return cels
```

and then, when I enter:

```
convert(10)
```

I receive this error:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I cannot understand why I am getting this because it seems like I have followed all the applicable rules. If anyone knows why I am getting this, Id love to know!

Comment: ^Update: When I copied the function onto this site, it got rid of the spacing. But, in Python, after the colon there is a new line that follows the automatic indentation and then a new line also starts at 32.

Comment: The `return cels` identation must be aligned with `cels = fahr *1.8 + 32`'s.

Comment: @BenMogil The code in your answer works for me

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you are writing this in the terminal and not a .py file, so you need to be careful with entering code. Here, you need a blank line between your indentations. Look at this:

```
>>> def convert (fahr):
...     cels = fahr *1.8 + 32
...     return cels
...
```

Notice the `...`: python still expects me to be inserting indented code. You need to leave a blank line and then type `covert(10)`, like this:

```
>>> def convert (fahr):
...     cels = fahr *1.8 + 32
...     return cels
...
>>> convert(10)
```

Notice the `convert(10)` follows `>>>`.

This generates a syntax error:

```
>>> def convert (fahr):
...     cels = fahr *1.8 + 32
...     return cels
... convert(10)
```

> File "<stdin>", line 4
> convert(10)
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

This contrasts with a .py file. In a .py file, this is perfectly legal (although it is discouraged by convention):

```
def convert (fahr):
    cels = fahr *1.8 + 32
    return cels
convert(10)
# runs without error
```

Comment: Just for my own knowledge, what is the difference between the terminal and a .py file?

Comment: @BenMogil Not much. 1) This syntax is different. 2) In the .py file, writing `convert(10)` will not print the result, you must write `print(convert(10))`. You should be doing most of your work in a .py file. I can't think of anything other than the above 2 differences, although I rarely write in the console as it makes debugging and reusing code more difficult.

Comment: Oh so you suggest I do not use IDLE for my learning? I am really trying to immerse myself in Python right now and learn as much as I possibly can, and I thought that IDLE was the best environment for me to do this in, but I'd love to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Break it into multiple lines :

```py
def convert (fahr):
    cels = fahr * 1.8 + 32
    return cels
```

The reason why you were getting a syntax error is that you had two statements one after the other on the same line. If you *really* want it in one line, you can write :

```py
def convert (fahr): cels = fahr *1.8 + 32 ; return cels
```

But the standard practice in Python is to have only one statement per line.

Also, your function says 0°F = 32°C. I think it should rather be the opposite (0°C = 32°F).

Comment: I input it the exact way you did there. It just changed it when I copied it into this forum.

Comment: @BenMogil If you input it the same way as I did, it should work. I tested it in IDLE (python 3.9.1) and it works

Comment: That's so weird ... I am in IDLE 3.8.3 Shell and it does not work ...

Comment: There is no semi-colon ... just a standard colon

Comment: @BenMogil edit your answer to put your code into a code block (three backticks, line feed, your code, line feed, three backticks) so it'll keep the spacing

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: @BenMogil yes, it is

Answer (score 0):

In Python, all statements must be on a new line. So when you define a function using `def` you must have each statement (say a step or a calculation) of the function on the new line. So the correct code would look like this,

```py
def convert(fahr):
   cels = (fahr *1.8) + 32
   return cels
```

A simple refactor that removes the redundant variable is this,

```py
def convert(fhr):
   return (fahr *1.8) + 32
```

You can then simplify this even more, which you shouldn't really use generally, is using a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) the code for this would look something like this,

```py
convert = lambda fahr: (fahr *1.8) + 32
```

The advantage of this is that the function is defined only in one line, but it can make the code difficult to read. So it should be used sparingly. There is also a final way, which I originally didn't include as it a prime example of what you should not do. You can put multiple statements on the same line but separate each one using a semi-colon. The code for this would look like this,

```py
def convert(fahr): cels = (1.8 * fahr) + 32; return cels
```

All of these functions would be called by the line `convert(x)` or whatever number you would like.

Comment: Thanks Luke, but as I mentioned above, I input the code with the exact spacing that you did and I am still receiving the error. StackOverflow just converted it to that for some reason upon me making this post.

Comment: Are you running it through the python shell? If not try it in a python file. It would be File > new the paste in the code, then go  Run > Run with interactive shell. It will most likely be an issue with the indentation or something when you copy and pase.

Comment: I am running it through the python shell

Comment: @LukeBraithwaite you can put multiple statements on the same line with semicolons, but it isn't considered good practice.

Comment: @BenMogil what error is it? Is it still a syntax error?

Comment: Whoops just seen the other answer. The issue was just that you hadn't pressed enter enough to escape from the function body. This meant the interpreter thought the `convert(10)` was part of the function body so must be indented. It is just a weird quirk of the interactive shell.